# Google tag manager trigger not firing when set to URL contains [some text]

Tags: google-tag-manager

I am trying to track page view events of certain pages of my site.

The GTM trigger does NOT fire if I set it up as:

```
PAGE URL / contains / chinese
```

But it works if I set it as:

```
PAGE URL / equals / www.example.com/booksaboutchinesefood
```

I really want to use the first way (page url / contains).

Any idea how I can make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Page URL` refers to the hostname, so in your case "www.example.com" which does not include the `/booksaboutchinesefood` part, where as what you are probably needing is `Page Path`, which will look at the string after the hostname, ie. `/booksaboutchinesefood`.

So change `Page URL` to `Page Path` and your trigger should fire.

Comment: Thank you.  I tried that, but unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: Can you include screenshots of your tags and triggers? You might also want to try a regex match, so `Page Path Matches Regex .*chinese.*` or something like that.

Comment: I just figured it out...the link was in chinese characters, so in GTM it was garbled like this:   %99%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88%E3%83%AA%E3%82.   So after some trial and error I could figure out which part of the garbled text was the string I wanted.  then youu way worked.   Thank you very much.

Comment: To avoid confusion for future visitors I want to point out that Page Url _does_ contain the full page page (in addition to hostname, protocol etc). Page Url vs. Page Path mostly makes a difference if you have "begins with" as condition (since page Url will always start with the protocol).

Comment: @EikePierstorff, ack yes! You are absolutely right. Thanks for clarifying. Must have been something in the koolaid i drank.

Comment: Also, no one mentioned here one of the most common mistake: giving multiple conditions/urls/regex etc. inside the same trigger. That won't work, cos all of them need to be true the same time. This article explains how to make proper OR condition: https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/or-condition-in-google-tag-manager-triggers-3-options/